# How to extract url paths recursively

Tags: regex, awk

i want to list all endpoints in a list of url like

```
https://test123.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://test456.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://test789.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
```

into output like

```
https://test123.com/
https://test123.com/endpoint1/
https://test123.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/
https://test123.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://test456.com/
https://test456.com/endpoint1/
https://test456.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/
https://test456.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
```

And so on, listing all endpoints recursively so i would do something with each endpoint.

I tried to use this but it print it separately.
`awk '$1=$1' FS="/" OFS="\n"`

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
match($0,/http[s]?:\/\/[^/]*\//){
  first=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  num=split(val,array,"/")
  print first
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    value=(value?value "/":"")array[i]
    print first value
  }
  val=first=value=""
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                          ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/http[s]?:\/\/[^/]*\//){              ##Using match function which matches http OR https :// then till first occurrence of /
  first=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)              ##Creating first with sub-string which starts from RSTART till RLENGTH value of current line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                ##Creating val which has rest of line out of match function in 3rd line of code.
  num=split(val,array,"/")                     ##Splitting val into array with delimiter / here.
  print first                                  ##Printing first here.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                         ##Starting for loop till value of num from i=1 here.
    value=(value?value "/":"")array[i]         ##Creating value which has array[i] and keep adding in its previous value to it.
    print first value                          ##Printing first and value here.
  }
  val=first=value=""                           ##Nullify variables val, first and value here.
}
'  Input_file                                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I'm wondering if that could be more simple even if I used anything rather than awk

Comment: @Emad, I have added detailed explanation to my solution which will help you to understand it better. I tried to write it more generic solution, its not tough please go through it and any queries please do let me know here cheers.

Comment: Good job @RavinderSingh13! The only other way to approach it would be a few lines longer and slower by using *parameter expansions* in a shell script. It will be hard to beat `awk` with `split()`.

Comment: I think I need to go deep in awk to understand what just happened, could you recommend thing to me?

Comment: @Emad, sure,this is my fav link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info where you will get all details for `awk` cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

With two loops:

```
awk '{
       x=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3            # x contains prefix https://
       for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) {        # NF is number of last element
         printf("%s", x)             # print prefix
         for(j=4; j<=i; j++){
           printf("%s%s", OFS, $j)   # print / and single element
         }
         print ""
       }
     }' FS='/' OFS='/' file
```

Output:

```
https://test123.com
https://test123.com/endpoint1
https://test123.com/endpoint1/endpoint2
https://test123.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://test456.com
https://test456.com/endpoint1
https://test456.com/endpoint1/endpoint2
https://test456.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://test789.com
https://test789.com/endpoint1
https://test789.com/endpoint1/endpoint2
https://test789.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, NR, **NF**, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'/' '{ep=$1 FS FS; for (i=3;i<NF;i++) print ep=ep $i FS; print ep $NF}' file
https://test123.com/
https://test123.com/endpoint1/
https://test123.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/
https://test123.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://test456.com/
https://test456.com/endpoint1/
https://test456.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/
https://test456.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://test789.com/
https://test789.com/endpoint1/
https://test789.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/
https://test789.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using perl.

```
perl -F/ -le 'print; while (3 < @F) { pop @F; print join("/", @F, "") }' input_file
```

Gives the following for your sample input.

```
https://test123.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://test123.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/
https://test123.com/endpoint1/
https://test123.com/
https://test456.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://test456.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/
https://test456.com/endpoint1/
https://test456.com/
https://test789.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/endpoint3
https://test789.com/endpoint1/endpoint2/
https://test789.com/endpoint1/
https://test789.com/
```

See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches look for `-Fpattern`.